# Dynamically Changing Boostrap title onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Could you please help me with a way to dynamically change the modal tile?

I need users to see different tile for each button they click, I have created a prototype in html and please let me know whether there is a a better/secure way to achieve this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="address"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Title 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 1</a>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 2</a>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 3</a>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 4</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/africanheart/L17c7y91/

Comment: The title of the question demonstrating about the Title of the model. But the explanation is about Tile of the Button. Which should we can understand? please edit the question to understand

Answer (score 2):

To get Dynamic Tiles, I think this is the perfect Solution.
I Added One Class and Removed one Class for your code
And I added Some of Tiles Classes in array in my Javascript.

Just Look At the Code Snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L17c7y91/1/)

```js
var cars = ["glyphicon-film","glyphicon-th-large", "glyphicon-th", "glyphicon-th-list"];
var i=0;
$(".tile").addClass(cars[0])
$(".mybtn").click(function(){
$(".tile").removeClass(cars[i])
i++;
if(i<4){
$(".tile").addClass(cars[i])
}
else{
i=0;
$(".tile").addClass(cars[i])
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This is some text.</p> 


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="address">
     
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger mybtn"><span class="glyphicon tile"></span> Title 1</a> 
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger mybtn"><span class="glyphicon tile"></span> Title 2</a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger mybtn"><span class="glyphicon tile"></span> Title 3</a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger mybtn"><span class="glyphicon tile"></span> Title 4</a>
</div>

</body>
</htmclassl>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Show your ***modal*** using a ***javascript*** method. And change title before showing modal. Here is the example

Here I used showModal() method to show the modal.

```
function showModal(title){
   $('.modal-title').html(title); // changing the title of modal
   $('#modal').modal('show');     // showing modal
}
```

And calling the method from `href="javascript:showModal('Title 1');"` in `anchor` tag

```js
function showModal(title){
$('.modal-title').html(title);
$('#modal').modal('show');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="address"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Title 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:showModal('Title 1');" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:showModal('Title 2');" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 2</a>
    <a href="javascript:showModal('Title 3');" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 3</a>
    <a href="javascript:showModal('Title 4');" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 4</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right approach to your problem. It is in the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) and is dynamic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var title = btn.data('title');
    $(this).find('.modal-title').text(title);
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This is some text.</p> 


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="address">
     
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-title="Title 1" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 1</a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-title="Title 2" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 2</a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-title="Title 3" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 3</a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-title="Title 4" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 4</a>
</div>
```

It uses the "data-*" attribute pattern and can retrieve more information from attribute of the caller button

Answer (score -1):

A small JQuery code to help you achieve the change in modal-title.

```js
$(".btn-danger").click(function(e) {
  $(".modal-title").text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This is some text.</p>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="address">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Title 1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 1</a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 2</a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 3</a>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Title 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: in this case click on close button and see

Comment: @Nirajpatel - Fixed it. And that was still not a problem anyways, but got it optimized. Wondering why you gave downvote for this?!?

Answer (score -1):

**solved your issue please have a look on this put this js below the code**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-danger").click(function(){
        //alert($(this).text())
        title = $(this).text();
        $('.modal-title').html(title);
    });
});
</script>
```